# Maximum number of columns per table in SQLite Manager

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to increase the number of available columns of my table to about 25 or even more.

However, the SQLite Manager add-on for Mozilla products that I'm using supports the maximum of 20 columns per table.

How can I create a table with more than 20 columns?

Comment: I think this is a limitation of SQLite Manager. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597023/how-to-add-more-than-20-columns-in-sqlite-3-for-iphone